# Electrical receptacle (outlet) getting 84 v black-white and 120 v black to ground

Tags: electrical, wiring

I've working on a 25 year old mobile home electrical outlet.

Power went off to outlet. Circuit breaker is still on (untripped) and other outlets on same circuit (but now downstream) are live.

I pulled off outlet to examine wires.

- White
- Black
- uncoated (ground I assume)

Measured with multimeter:

- 84 v   Black to White
- 123 v  Black to ground
- 15v  White to ground

What's going on here?

Comment: Plug a load into the outlet (carefully), turn it on, and measure again. Does black-white go to 0V and white-ground go to 120V?

Comment: You can search for "phantom voltage" or "induced voltage".  Chances are good that the neutral wire connection has broken somewhere, but since it runs parallel to the hot wire, the voltmeter is picking up a small voltage on it, but that voltage is so weak it can't power anything.

Comment: Are any backstabs used?